# css change property on hover

Tags: css, hover

Is there a way to change the css property for example of a  box when an  element (inside the ) is hover?

for example if I have:

```
<table>
<tr><td><a>.....</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to change the property of the container td when the link a has the mouse over. Is it possible?

Sorry, I have not explained well.
I have a , not a table...it was only an example....
I have

```
<ul>
<li><a>.....
```

in my css I have:

```
#navigation li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #333;
text-transform: none;
}
#navigation li:hover {
color: white;
background-color: #333;
}
#navigation li a:hover {
color: white;
background-color: #333;
}
```

but It does not works because if I go on the link it's ok, but if I go with the mouse in the li but off the link the color of the text does not change...

Comment: Yes, it is. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204472/jquery-hover-effect-over-table This will show you how to add hover action to a table element. Following this, look into jQuery css http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but It does not works because if I go on the link it's ok, but if I go with the mouse in the li but off the link the color of the text does not change...

That's because you're putting the hover on the link itself. If you want the link to react when you mouse over the li, simply change where you put the hover pseudo-class:

```
li:hover a {
    color: #d2d2d2;
}
```

This basically says "when the li is hovered, the link inside it should change to these styles."

Alternatively, you can add padding to the link (ex - `padding: 5px`), making its reaction field larger. So:

```
li a {
  display: block; /* Required to make it honor padding. */
  padding: 10px;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #d2d2d2;
}
```

As long as you don't have your `li` elements set to a larger size than the `a` element (via height, width, margin, and/or padding), then the `li` will "shrink-wrap" the `a` and be the same size as the total size of the link.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
#navigation li a:hover {
```

try

```
#navigation li:hover a {
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant change a property of a parent element, but you can trigger a hover event on the parent td itself:

```
table td:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add display: block to the anchor element which would make the anchor fill the li... Depending on indentation on the ul etc etc..

```
li a { display: block; }
```